# Why do RSA keys look like they do?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

Im trying to get a better understanding on RSA encryption so i have my program display the key it generates, but according to my understanding of RSA encryption, the keys should be only numbers, but my program has a long string of numbers, characters, and letters.

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Get user input for plaintext
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the plaintext:");
        string plaintext = Console.ReadLine();

        // Generate RSA key pair (for simplicity, we use a fixed key size of 2048 bits)
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
        {
            // Display the public key
            Console.WriteLine("Public Key:");
            Console.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(false));

            // Encrypt the plaintext
            byte[] plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(plaintextBytes, fOAEP: false);

            // Display the encrypted string
            string encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Text:");
            Console.WriteLine(encryptedString);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

when my program displays the public key it looks like this

```
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>m/DXR9Ld2vAAIS3sATZGx2z4lsZeeImu7qQzAW6j+EGIcU6ToGBOVK3kCYcbv+o884HT/hDj9M/FV9Tc/apaFREqucSw973pJyNXnp2bvO8DwO9XohBPX5lWognAWr4KDybMn9oBuqR4fAYck2ym1uYtXxGetSgf3+qgX9RcbZGi7ifafJyw1hGNLzpA6d5pZkyXUvrpDz4YLT5vbJ8xoFEFfxYV6zA5EZcEi/9w8IJaU/ypFpdmZhMtmDSXKSBJ9MVVridnAjwahwWuZNCp9rRsbsTiGEvPPvbnW1WXrbOxT41IrDuGr/gNX2GEkAv+SNVXUN8z2LcHtIHRTj7/GQ==</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

if the keys are generated purely with math and numbers, i dont understand how or why the key looks like it does? my only idea would be the line
Console.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(false));
but what does that line mean exactly?

Comment: The XML format is a W3C standard, which is described e.g. here https://www.w3.org/TR/xkms2/#XKMS_2_0_Section_8_2. The Base64 decoded data must be interpreted in *big endian* order (not in the *little endian* order, as the answer suggests).

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring?view=net-7.0#remarks), `RSA.ToXmlString` returns an XML representation of the keypair (either just the public part, by default, or both the public and private parts).

The cryptic-looking text is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded binary data; `AQAB` is the encoding of the bytes '01 00 01', which in turn, when interpreted as a big-endian integer, encode the exponent 65537:

```
$ python3
>>> import base64
>>> int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(b"AQAB"), "big")
65537
```

The same idea stands for `Modulus`, which is a pretty big number (the decimal form is 616 digits long).

As for what these numbers mean and how they're used, you'll have to refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation).

Comment: why the python code?

Comment: The Base64 decoded data is to be interpreted in the big endian order, not little endian. This is irrelevant for the exponent (as 010001 is identical in both cases), but not for the other data (such as the modulus).

Comment: Ahh i see, thx a lot. this is for a big project where i also need to explain the maths, so if i want it to just display the keys in the pure numbers, how do i modify the code to do that?

Comment: @MathiasHauvgaard `new BigInteger(RSA.ExportParameters().Modulus, true, true)` should get you a number.

Comment: @AKX im trying that but get an error on the ExportParameters part and the Modulus part. if i instead add a `var KeyNumbers = ` before the new BigInteger, i only get an error on the exportParameters part. the error message says something like theres no parameter given, but even if i add true or false in the parenthasees, the error is still there

Comment: Well, you'll need to read up on the docs for `BigInteger` then – I don't have a proper C# environment right now. But the point is you need to turn the byte array you get from `Modulus` into an integer, and that is approximately the way to do it.